# Spring 3.1.0 mvc binding modelattribute along with requestbody

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, annotations, modelattribute

I am new to Spring 3.1.0, and am trying to create an application, which can be exposed as a web application as well as web services.
For a POST where i am submitting a form object using the `@ModelAttribute`. I also want to expose this method which can consume the same object as XML, through any poster.

Shall i use both `@ModelAttribute` & `@RequestBody` together. I have already added the consumes property in the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit form, data comes in form-encoded manner, and when you use XML/JSON it comes as a string in body. You'd better place all your common logic to intermediate service layer and call it in your controllers. As a result it allows you to simply build REST services on top of existing HTML pages with forms:

```
public class Service {
    public void registerUser(User user){
    }
}

@RequestMapping("users")
public class FormController{
    @Autowired private Service service;

    @RequestMapping("register")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute User user){
        service.registerUser(user);
    }
}

@RequestMapping("service/v1")
public class RESTController{
    @Autowired private Service service;

    @RequestMapping("users/register")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@RequestBody User user){
        service.registerUser(user);
    }
}
```

Actually, you can even put this in one controller.

Comment: Hey thanks but i already thought about this, however this would be like creating a similar method again, which actually defeats the purpose of the whole discussion. I am not very sure if separate methods is the only way out for it. .